# Mup setup/deploy error when using meteor-up

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

I want to deploy my website using meteor-up.  I want to deploy it to a EC2 instance on AWS.  I have created my mup.json file and configured it as follows:

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "ec2-52-24-95-147.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
      "username": "ubuntu",
      //"password": "password"
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      "pem": "C:/Users/username/meteor.pem"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.36 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.35",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": false,

  // Show a progress bar during the upload of the bundle to the server. 
  // Might cause an error in some rare cases if set to true, for instance in Shippable CI
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "Homepage",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "C:/website",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "ec2-52-24-95-147.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "PORT": 80,
    "METEOR_ENV": "production"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working and I am getting the following error:

```
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
 ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT {public IP from AWS}:22
    at Object.exports._errnoExcpetion (util.js:837:11)
    at exports._excpetionWithHostPort (util.js:860:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1060:14)
```

Comment: Can you post some output from `mup logs -f`

Comment: It throws me the exact same error message.  Thank you for taking interest, I really want to get my website up.  Any other ideas?

Comment: How about `mup logs -n 300`? You're using `mup` or `mupx`?

Comment: I am using mup.  I entered mup logs -n 300, and again the same error was displayed.  Still really lost here

Answer (score 0):

Per the [https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up](http://Repo%20docs), try setting the **DEBUG** environment variable:

**Verbose Output**

If you need to see the output of meteor-up (to see more precisely where it's failing or hanging, for example), run it like so:

```
DEBUG=* mup <command>
```

where  is one of the mup commands such as setup, deploy, etc.

Comment: I found what you are referring to in the meteor-up github repository but this function does not seemed to be recognized it says.  Thank you for taking an interest, I really want to solve this.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Sure, please post the output of running this: DEBUG=* mup deploy

Comment: it says 'DEBug' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.  I was able to run the mup logs -f command which rendered the same error as posted.  I have a feeling that its a connection issue that is created connecting to the files util.js but I do not know what it could be when I look at the files

Comment: Maybe you're running Windows? If so, try running as an Administrator. At any rate, I found your error message at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4090 if you'd like to review the comments. HTH.

Comment: No I can get meteor to work as a command.  My whole website is set up and ready and works on my localhost using meteor.  Yes, I use windows but I am running as an administrator, i.e. I am the admin.  It is password protected however, could that be interfering?